# Change axis in R with different number of datas

Tags: r, axis

I want to change x-axis in my graphic, but it doesn't work properly with axis(). Datas in the graphic are daily datas and I want to show only years. Hope someone understands me and find a solution. This is how it looks like now: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LUnxX.jpg) and this is how it looks like with the code >axis (1, at = seq(1800, 1975, by = 25), las=2): [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NH0Ky.jpg)

Comment: Can you please show what the current graph looks like, and tell us what the desired output should be?

Comment: I added a graph above. 70000 are days, but I need to show years (from 1800 to 1975).

Comment: Please include your code and show us what your data looks like.

Comment: Assuming your data for x is in 'date' format, you can look up scale_x_date() and use that to control the x-axis.

Comment: I have a txt file including one precipitation data each day (for 195 years). I just scan that file.txt (X=scan("C:\\...\\file.txt")) and plot it: >plot(X,type="l",ylab="mm/d",xlab="years")

Answer (score 0):

EDITED based on comment by @scoa

As a quick and dirty solution, you can simply enter the following line after your `plot()` line:

```
# This reads as, on axis x (1), anchored at the first (day) value of 0
# and last (day) value of 63917 with 9131 day year increments (by)
# and labels (las) perpendicular (2) to axis (for readability)
# EDITED: and AT the anchor  locations, put the labels
# 1800 (year) to 1975 (year) in 25 (year) increments
axis (1, at = seq(0, 63917, by = 9131), las=2, labels=seq(1800, 1975, by=25));
```

For other parameters, check out `?axis`.  As @scoa mentioned, this is approximate.  I have used 365.25 as a day-to-year conversion, but it's not quite right.  It should suffice for visual accuracy at the scale you have provided.  If you need precise conversion from days to years, you need to operate on your original data set first before plotting.

Comment: I already tried it and it doesn't work properly because it appeares just the first date! How can it be?

Comment: @Sagra Because you x axis seems to represents days, not years... Maybe something along those lines will work: `axis (1, at = seq(0, 195*365, by = 365*25), las=2,labels = seq(1800, 1975, by = 25))` (also it is incorrect, as it does not take leap years into account)

Comment: Good call, @scoa.  I had the anchors and labels confused.  I've merged our answers using an approximate days->year conversion.

Answer (score 0):

Without a reproducible code is not easy to get what could be the problem. I try a "quick and dirt" approach.

High level plots are composed by elements that are sub-composed themselves. Hence, separate drawing commands could turn in use by allowing a finer control on the plotting procedure.

In practice, the first thing to do is plot "nothing".

```
> plot(x, y, type = "n", xlab = "", ylab = "", axes = F)
```

`type = "n"` causes the data to not be drawn. `axes = F` suppresses the axis and the box around the plot. In spite of that, the plotting region is ready to show the data. 
The main benefit is that now the plotting area is correctly dimensioned. Try now to add the desired `x` axis as you tried before.

```
> points(x, y)    # Plots the data in the area 
> axis()          # Plots the desired axis with your scale
> title()         # Plots the desired titles
> box()           # Prints the box surrounding the plot
```